# How to adjust brake level movement on hydraulic brake?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers, adjustment

My bicycle has Tektro Auriga hydraulic disc brakes. I can adjust how far the level stitches out with a small screw (see [here](http://www.tektro.com/dowfile.php?p=25), figure c2).

I was wondering if it is possible to adjust how much the brake lever can be pulled before it bites. There seems to be considerable difference between the front and rear brakes in how much pull is needed.

With V brakes that use cables, one can simply pull the cable a bit on the brake's end. Is there a simple solution with hydraulic brakes?

Comment: That is more about your levers, it will be in the lever manual, not in the brake caliper manual. There should be a reach adjustment screw on your levers.

Comment: @VladimirF I found the reach adjustment screw, but that does controls the outermost position. What I am looking to control is how much it can be pulled, from outermost to innermost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurigas don't have bite point adjustment. For the most part it's a feature found only on some upper end hydraulic brakes.

The rear brake being a little softer and longer to engage is normal since the line is longer. But if it's more than a little, that can be a sign of other problems that bite point adjustment wouldn't help with anyway, like air in the line or a piston movement problem. If the rear pads are getting worn out that will also contribute.